# MySQL to PostgreSQL migration converted camelCase columns to simple format. Leading to Column does not exist error in Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, django-orm, pgloader

I migrated MySQL database to PostgreSQL using pgloader. I am using Django ORM to execute the queries. The database fields are defined in camel case but after the migration the postgres columns are replaced to normal format. e.g brochureName is changed to brochurename. This is causing "Column does not exist" error in the application.
What is the best way to handle this issue? I have lots of columns and queries already defined at many instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with `WITH quote identifiers`

```
LOAD database
    from mysql://
    into postgresql://
WITH quote identifiers
```